# Automatic enum case count and indexes in enum with values

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have an enum

```swift
enum MyEnum {
  case Position(x: Int, y: Int)
  case Name(String)
}
```

and I want to be able to do the following:

```swift
MyEnum.caseCount // returns 2
```

```swift
let val = MyEnum.Position(x: 0, y: 0)
val.idx // returns 0
MyEnum.Name("My awesome name").idx // returns 1
```

So I want a variable holding the total amount of cases + on a specific enum case I want to know its index in the enum

Is there a way I can automatically derive this (probably will be using a protocol)?

I have looked at `CaseIterable`, but that can't automatically be implemented for enums holding values. I also can't do = `enum MyEnum: Int` because of the value again.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum) had a lot of answers, all implented in Swift 3, and none of those seemed to still work.

If unsafe code would have to be used for this, I would be ok with that.

Something like this would work ofcourse, however it is a lot of boilerplate for the user to write:

```swift
extension MyEnum {
  func id() -> Int {
    switch self {
      case .Position: return 0
      case .Name: return 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have any snippets of what you tried?

Comment: @JCode I have linked the SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum). I've tried all solutions that didn't mention anything about enums with raw values. But none of these answers actually worked.

Comment: You have an enum with associated values which means the number of cases is unknown, `.Name("a")` and `.Name("b")` are two different cases for instance. You could supply that yourself but given the type of associated values you have I suspect the number of cases are unlimited?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson case `.Name("a")` and `.Name("b")` should be treated as the same index in this example

Comment: I have never done this in Swift but you can use a Mirror to get the names of the cases by reflection, right? That should let you determine the case count and find the index of a given case. Something along the lines of [Reflectable enums in Swift 3](https://ijoshsmith.com/2017/04/08/reflectable-enums-in-swift-3/) or [Dynamic access of Swift Enum associated values](https://medium.com/@nguyenminhphuc/reflection-of-enum-in-swift-ed5a31573f28).

Comment: @DavidConrad I've had a quick look at those links, and it looks like that's what I'm after. Haven't had time to verify if this works for my use case yet, but should be able to in the next couple of days

Comment: @DavidConrad Seems like I'm unable to get the cases when using `Mirror(reflectin: MyEnum.self)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of my depth here. This is more complex than anything I have done with Swift. I just thought of how I might do it with Java reflection, and then Googled to see if there was something similar in Swift. I've only used Swift for pretty simple, straightforward things. Good luck, though!

Comment: @DavidConrad No worries! It was a good suggestion, just a bummer it’s not as powerful. I came up with a sub-optimal hacks solution, but it’s way slower than doing this manually, so currently it’s still manual.