# C++ Metaprogramming: Store integer by type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want to store integers for given types which should be used during compilation and during runtime.

Up to now I have the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_int { enum { result = -1 }; };
```

And I specialize for each type:

```
template<> struct my_int<a_type> { enum { result = 5 }; };
```

And I can check during compile time (of course the check here would be against another compile time constant):

```
static_assert(my_int<a_type>::result == 5, "Bla");
```

---

**Problem:** 
This works well, as long as the specialization is in the same namespace. But that is an inconvenience I want to get rid of. So I want to be able to use it in every namespace:

```
namespace foo {
  template<> struct my_int<a_type> { enum { result = 5 }; };
}

namespace bar {
  template<> struct my_int<b_type> { enum { result = 7 }; };
}
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

C++11 and boost is ok for my situation, if really needed.

**Update:** Seems I gave to little information. The types are mainly `enum classes`. If you're really interested you can see the real implementation here, http://www.codeduce.com/extra/enum_tools, download the zip and in the header line 33, 34.

Comment: How about `template<> struct my_int<foo::a_type> { enum { result = 5 }; };`

Comment: Well the point is, that this specialization is part of a larger macro, which needs to be used in different namespaces. So, I would need to get out of every namespace and back in ih the preceding namespace in a macro...

Comment: try to use `::my_int` or `::otherNS::my_int`

Comment: @Paranaix: `error: class template specialization of 'my_int' must originally be declared in namespace 'otherNS'`.

Comment: @Paranaix: same here, I tried that: `error: global qualification of class name is invalid before '{' token`

Comment: Is it realistic to define a template per namespace and then aggregate all these ?

Comment: @Antoine I don't see how such an aggregation function could look like.

Comment: The following may help for enum class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102582/how-can-i-count-the-items-in-an-enum

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, but those usually alter the enum, and that is exactly what I don't want, and why I'm doing all this enum stuff.

Comment: @MikeM: If you're interested I added an answer which aggregates from all namespaces.

Comment: @Antoine Thank you, I saw it, but I need some time to understand it, I'll answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I found the problem description easy to misunderstand, but the linked code makes it clear.  In C++11 it's easy:

```
#define SETUP_ENUM_LENGTH(enum_type, length)                                   \
  static constexpr int enum_length(enum_type*) { return length; }
```

and a

```
  for (int i = 0; i < enum_length((Enum*)0); ++i) {
```

in the right place.  Here's a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/size.hpp>

/**
 * Macro to setup an enum completely.
 * First parameter is the name, following are the states as plain text.
 */
#define DEF_ENUM(name, ...)                                                    \
  enum class name : uint8_t { __VA_ARGS__ };                                   \
  SETUP_ENUM_LENGTH(name, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))

/**
 * Once an enum class is defined, this macro makes the size publicly available.
 * Needed by enum_array. Already included in DEF_ENUM.
 */
#define SETUP_ENUM_LENGTH(enum_type, length)                                   \
  static constexpr int enum_length(enum_type*) { return length; }

/**
 * Function to iterate over all elements of an enum.
 */
template<typename Enum>
void enum_for_each(const std::function<void(Enum e)> &fct) {
  for (int i = 0; i < enum_length((Enum*)0); ++i) {
    fct(static_cast<Enum>(i));
  }
}

namespace n {
    DEF_ENUM(demo,u,v,w,x,y,z,a,b,c);
}
namespace m {
    DEF_ENUM(demo,a=3,b=1,c=4,d=1,e=5);
}

using std::cout;
int main()
{
    enum_for_each<n::demo>([](n::demo e) { cout<<int(e); });
    cout<<'\n';
    enum_for_each<m::demo>([](m::demo e) { cout<<int(e); });
    cout<<'\n';

    int ndemo[enum_length((n::demo*)0)];
    int mdemo[enum_length((m::demo*)0)];

    cout << sizeof ndemo << ' ' << sizeof mdemo << '\n';
}
```

As a side note, that `static_cast<Enum>(i)` looks troublesome, does it really do the right thing with the `m::demo` enum?

To preserve the original templated-`enum_length` usage and so make the array-allocation usage a bit prettier is easy from here, rename the function `enum_length_helper` and then

```
template<typename Enum>
struct enum_length {
   enum result=enum_length_helper((Enum*)0);
};
```

Comment: Now, you propose something different that what the OP try :-) And it seems correct. Sorry if my remarks and OP were not clear. (previous remarks deleted)

Comment: Thank you, that is a very neat idea, it is very short and works well. Sorry, if my problem description was not clear enough. Considering your `namespace m` example, no that won't work correctly, but using `DEF_ENUM` in a plain state you get additional compiler checks for enum related data, that's what I'm after. I haven't seem a failsafe solution of this task yet.

Comment: @MikeM Looking back I should have gotten it.  Oh, well.  The confusion gave it time to steep a bit and all's well.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible for your use-case, you could do specialization on a namespace basis and then aggregate as follows, using C++11 since you mentioned it but can work without.

Assume you have a number of namespaces `ns_1` to `ns_k` like this:

```
namespace ns_i {
    template<class T> struct my_int: std::integral_constant<int, -1> {};
    /*...*/
    enum e_1 { /*...*/ };
    template<> struct my_int<e_1>: std::integral_constant<int, 101> {};
    /*...*/
    enum e_n { /*...*/ };
    template<> struct my_int<e_n>: std::integral_constant<int, 142> {};
    /*...*/
}
```

I assume you already have the means to do a unique numbering. Then you aggregate the `my_int` from all namespaces like this:

```
namespace your_lib {
    template<
      class T,
      template<class> class sources... /* any number of template classes,
                                          each taking one type argument */
    >
    struct Union:
      std::integral_constant<int, -1> {}; // default -1 for (empty template list)

    template<
      class T,
      template<class> class source,    // match first template
      template<class> class sources... // match all but first template
    >
    struct Union<T, source, sources...>:
      std::conditional<
        source::value == -1,
        union<T, sources...>, // recursively call union on all but first tempalte
        source                // or if there's a value in first, use it
      > {};

    template<class T> struct my_int :
      Union<T, ns_1::my_int, /*...,*/ ns_k::my_int> {};
    /* here you could use boost preprocessor to iterate over the namespaces
       since you mentionned it */
}
```

Comment: So he has to include the whole word to use this solution :-/

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal. But the unique numbering mechanism would also need to include everything I guess, so hopefully this doesn't add more dependencies?

Comment: Although I'm not going to use this in production since it's more then one place to change to add a new item, I learned something about metaprogramming. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using functions and ADL:

```
    #include <type_traits>

    enum TypeInfo
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            TypeA,
            TypeB
        };

    template <TypeInfo x>
    using TInfo = std::integral_constant<TypeInfo, x>;

    template <class T>
    TInfo<Unknown> TypeInfoFunc(T);

    template <class T>
    struct GetTypeInfo : decltype(TypeInfoFunc(std::declval<T>())){};

    namespace a{
        class A{};
        TInfo<TypeA> TypeInfoFunc(A);
    };

    namespace b {
        class B{};
        TInfo<TypeB> TypeInfoFunc(B);
    }

    int main()
    {
        static_assert(GetTypeInfo<a::A>::value == TypeA, "");
        static_assert(GetTypeInfo<b::B>::value == TypeB, "");
        return 0;
    }
```

The `TypeInfoFunc` is found using ADL meaning that it can be defined in the same namespace as the class your specializing it for.

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, I think I understand a bit better now.  The solution doesn't change much, simply make your function:

```
    namespace a
    {
        struct A{};//Or whatever class you want to hold data about your type
        A TypeInfoFunc(TInfo<TypeA>);
    }
```

and change `GetTypeInfo` to

```
    template <TypeInfo x>
    struct GetTypeInfo : decltype(TypeInfoFunc(TypeInfo<X>())) {};
```

This way you can call `GetTypeInfo<TypeA>` and access all the information in (in this case) class `A`.

Comment: This would mean, that for each new specialization there are two edits necessary? One entry for the enum and one `TInfo...`. Can one accomplish this with a macro?

Comment: @MikeM You can't extend an enum after if it's been declared, so no, I don't think you could do that with a macro.  You could not use an enum and use integer constants instead but that means you have to select yourself a unique integer for each class and you won't get an error for duplicate values (unless you explicitly test for that but that again means 2 updates necessary for each new class)

Comment: I think we missunderstand. The types for which I want to store additional information are `enum classes`. So I want to store e.g. the length of an `enum class` as a compile time constant, to work with it. There is no type trait for the length of an `enum class`. But I want as little overhead as possible for storing that additional information, and since we only need to count the arguments in the `enum class` definition to get the size, I do this with a macro.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible, but something like `TInfo<TypeA> TypeInfoFunc<5>(A)` would do, meaning `TypeInfoFunc` needs to be a template function over `int`.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand it. How would I add a specialization for e.g. `TypeA, 5`. `A TypeInfoFunc(TInfo<TypeA>);` doesn't allow for an integer, or does it need to be encoded in `enum TypeInfo` but then, what if I want to store 5 for two different `enum classes`?

Comment: @MikeM `struct A{static const int magic_number = 5;};`, then `GetTypeInfo<TypeA>::magic_number`.  Does this work for your purposes?

Comment: No, since A is an `enum class` and I need to store it like `enum class A {foo, bar}; store_length_somehow<A>(2);` I cannot or better want not add fields to the enum class which don't belong to the business logic it encodes.

Comment: @MikeM I'm afraid I don't understand how this is different from your usage in your question.  `#CREATE_CASE(enum_val, val) std::integral_constant<int, val> TypeInfoFunc(TInfo<enum_val>())` and then you can do `CREATE_CASE(TypeA, 5);  static_assert(GetTypeInfo<TypeA>::value == 5, "");`.  The `struct A{};` was just a placeholder for whatever class you want to use that's going to hold the information you want to access.

Comment: You're right, it's not different, I just needed to understand it. However, I don't see if one can go without registering the types in `TypeInfo`, without ending at the same solution as jthill posted. But ADL seems to be the way one has to go for this kind of problem. Thank you for your efforts, I learned quite a lot going through your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the need to specialize a structure if you move the type information in the type itself:

```
template <int V>
struct TypeInfo { enum { result = V, }; };

class yourClass : TypeInfo<2> //works better if you have an enum instad of number
{}
//...

static_assert(a_type::result == 2);
```

If you do this you will never have the problem with namespaces if the type is declared you will always have access to type info.

Comment: This works as long as you have control of every class you want to use this for.

Comment: @GuyGreer yes , it's hard if you already have a large codebase, but then again i don't think anyone wants custom static type info on all the code, you would need too many numbers.

Comment: Well, the types are mainly `enum classes`. It doesn't seem to work here, does it?

Comment: @MikeM just use a `std::integral_constant<TypeInfo, type>` to derive from, and then you have a nested `value` to get the enum constant back

Comment: @GuyGreer My types are `enum classes` so I cannot derive from anything, or can I? Though it was not possible.

Comment: [OT]: `static_assert` takes *two* arguments.