# How to assert whether a value is within an enums range

Tags: c++, c++03

I am reading a value from a byte stream and want to assert that this value is within an enums range. I was wondering if there's a more generic approach than the one below.

```
int nval = ReadValue();
Assert(nval);

bool Assert(nval)
{
 if(nval == zero || nval == one || nval==two || (nval>=reserved_low && nval <= reserved_high))
  return true;
 return false
}
    enum Foo
    {
     zero = 0,
     one = 1,
     two = 2,
     reserved_low = 3,
     reserved_high = 255,
    }
```

Comment: seems to me that you only need `nval>=zero && nval <= reserved_high`

Comment: You can specify additional constants in the enum `Foo_min = zero, Foo_max = reserved_high`.

Comment: Please, search your [question] on SO before ask.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102582/how-can-i-count-the-items-in-an-enum)

Answer (score 1):

Not in C++03, no.

Your way is pretty optimal (and certainly readable), although you could recognise that, given all your enums are in the range 0 to 255, `return !(nval & ~0xff);` would do the job.

You might be able to squeeze out a bit more performance using a `switch` and compare `nval>=reserved_low && nval <= reserved_high` in the `default` case.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that those optimizations would make much of a difference; the original code is pretty simple, so the compiler would probably do a better job of optimizing it than we would.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the compiler did collapse it to `!(nval & ~0xff)`

Comment: The above version (when fixed) just gets a `cmpl` followed by a `setbe` from [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/KS4GcZ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar but slightly cleaner trick:

```
enum Foo {
 zero = 0,
 one = 1,
 two = 2,
 reserved_low = 3,
 reserved_high = 255,
 foo_count
};

bool Assert(nval) {
  if(nval > zero && nval < foo_count) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Because *enum* increments each entry with 1, *count* will now be set to value 256. If you would add extra valid values later on *count* will automatically be updated.