number of enum items
If I have an enum defined like following:
enum CovariancesContext : int
{
    INVALID             = -1,
    HORIZONTAL          =  0,
    VERTICAL            =  1,
    NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS
};

I am wondering what the value is or NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS? I would think it should be 3?

what happened when you wrote code to inspect the value ? What value did you see?

"I would think it should be 3" - why is that ?

Its 2, since enum values get the next increment if it does not have a value.
the idiom of using "number of enum values" only works when you count from  and no holes between the values exist.

@Raildex Can you post your answer please? Thank you.

Remove the initialisation values, so INVALID is 0, and it will be 3.

sometimes what you really want is a std::[unordered_]map<std::string,int> rather than an enum.

@trojanfoe so I will have two 0s in the enums? Because both INVALID and HORIZONTAL are 0s.

they said "Remove the initialisation values" if you do that the enumerators values start at 0 and increment by 1, ie the last is the number of enumerators

No, I am suggesting you don't initialise any of the enums.  Often you want to know how many enums there are in order to setup a static array to map enums to string, for logging purposes, so you need to be careful if that's your plan.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2102582/4117728 unfortunately the first answer to explain why your case does not work is a long way to scroll down https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912865/4117728

https://godbolt.org/z/EG71rhshs

The value of NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS will be 2, not 3.
If you do not specify a value for an enum element, it will be given a value +1 of the preceding element, or 0 if there is no element. Since VERTICAL has a value of 1, NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS will be 1+1=2.
If you want NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS to be 3 in this example, you will have to assign it explicitly:
enum CovariancesContext : int
{
    INVALID             = -1,
    HORIZONTAL          =  0,
    VERTICAL            =  1,
    NUMBER_OF_CONTEXTS  =  3
};

