# BlackJack cards vector c++/random numbers

Tags: c++, enums, blackjack

I followed some of the answers here on the site but I still have a problem: after I generate my vector of cards when I run the program the card numbers are totally off:
first card:100
second card:22
third:0
fourth:0
fifth:28
etc.

This is my code:

```
    enum numar {AS=11 ,DOI=2, TREI=3, PATRU=4, CINCI=5, SASE=6, SAPTE=7, OPT=8,
NOUA=9, ZECE=10, VALET=10, DAMA=10, REGE=10,
PrimulNumar=AS, UltimulNumar=REGE};
enum culoare {INIMA, CAROU, NEGRU, TREFLA, PrimaCuloare=INIMA,
UltimaCuloare=TREFLA};



 int k=0;
        for (int r = PrimulNumar; r <= UltimulNumar; ++r) {
                for (int s = PrimaCuloare; s <= UltimaCuloare; s++) {
                        pc[k]= new Carte((numar)r, (culoare)s, false);
                        k++;
```

What should I do?

Comment: The code is in romanian but I think you will understand.

Comment: First of all I'm not sure if make sense to create 2 items in the enum with the same value. Could you please explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Elalfer: `enum numar` contains card ranks. Ace = 11, two = 2, etc. Ten == jack == queen == king == 10.

Comment: Is that homework ? For one thing, PrimulNumar=11 and UltimulNumar=10. I think your array is just uninitialized ^^

Comment: All an `enum` is in most languages is just a convenient way of declaring a bunch of integer constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So...replacing enums with values:

```
int k = 0;
for (int r = 11; r <= 10; ++r)
  for (int s = 0; s <= 3; ++s
  {
  }
```

See the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem. How can I do it anyway? I took the ideea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941890/c-enum-in-foreach

Comment: Note that they didn't set values for their enums.  That's an important detail that totally changes the outcome.  If you're having trouble sensing why, review enums in C++: http://enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Norman/enel315_winter1997/enum_types/

Comment: But I don't understand how to give the same value to ten jack queen and the king... That's why I tried to give values.

Comment: If you do that you'll not be able to tell them apart.

Comment: @Emil: You could let the compiler assign the enum values (so AS==0,DOI==2, ... REGE==12) and then use an array of scores for the ranks, i.e. `int scores[] = {11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10 10};`. Then scores[AS] == 11, scores[DAMA] == 10, etc.