# Why can't I increment a variable of an enumerated type?

Tags: c++

I have an enumerated type, `StackID`, and I am using the enumeration to refer to an index of a particular vector and it makes my code easier to read.

However, I now have the need to create a variable called `nextAvail` of type `StackID` (it actually refers to a particular stackID ). I tried to increment it, but in C++ the following is illegal:

```
nextAvail++;
```

Which sort of makes sense to me ... because there isn't any bounds checking.

I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but what's a good substitute?

---

I also want to link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390703/enumerate-over-an-enum-in-c/1391479#1391479).

Comment: Re *"the following is illegal"*: What is the actual compiler error message?

Comment: Is it "`error: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'StackID')`"?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but what's a good substitute?

Overloading `operator++`:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead! 
StackID& operator++(StackID& stackID)
{
#if MY_ENUMS_ARE_CONTIGUOUS && I_DO_NOT_WORRY_ABOUT_OVERFLOW
  return stackID = static_cast<StackID>( ++static_cast<int>(stackID) );
#else
  switch(stackID) {
    case value1 : return stackID = value2;
    case value2 : return stackID = value3;
    ...
    case valueN : return stackID = value1;
  }
  assert(false);
  return stackID; // some compilers might warn otherwise
#endif
}

StackID operator++(StackID& stackID, int)
{
  StackID tmp(stackID);
  ++stackID;
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: @sbi - It would certainly make things simple for me to do this. but what do you say to the posters who suggest that an `enum` is meant to express a set of arbitrary values?

Comment: @BeeBand - if there is any use at all for the '++', I assume you have a good reason to go beyond the conventional C++ use of enums as compile-time checked ints. On the other hand, Sbi's code could do with some bound-checking.

In Java, enums are just a sort of lightweight classes with unmodifiable members -- it is accepted practice to place methods in them. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html.

Comment: @BeeBand: I don't agree. Probably five out of ten textbook `enum` examples are something like `enum month { Jan, Feb, ..., Dec };` and thus a perfect example for enenumerations that can increment. During the last >15 years of doing C++, I have overloaded `operator++` for enumerations probably less than five times. But I _have_ done it.

Comment: @GMan & @Martin: `<sigh>` Can you tell I'm on vacation, sitting in the garden, with my laptop on my knees twice a day and am to lazy to fire up the compiler? @BeeBand: Sorry for screwing this so badly. Thankfully, the community catches these.

Comment: @sbi Added a missing curly brace on the `switch` statement - hope that's ok. Just commenting this because I got surprised everyone passed right through it.

Comment: @Streppel: Thanks! (Of course, since I qualified my code with a warning, I don't feel bad about missing a brace... `:´^>` )

Comment: Hi, This is working for Pre operation like ++ Var. But  for Post operation like Var++, its not working..

Comment: @Jasmine: That's what the second overload is for. Also have a look at the [operator overloading FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/140719).

Answer (score 23):

Because enumerations do not have to be contiguous. E.g., take this example:

```
enum Colors {
 cRed, // = 0
 cBlue, // = 1
 cGreen = 3
}
```

What should happen in this scenario?

```
Colors color = cBlue;
Colors other = color++;
```

Should `other` be `cGreen` or should it be 2? In that case, it's not a valid enumeration member anymore. What about this?

```
Colors color = cGreen;
Colors other = color++;
```

Should `other` be `cRed` (wrap around) or 4?

As you can see, being able to increment enumeration values introduces a whole lot of questions and complicates the simple mechanism that they intend to be.

If all you care about is the integer value being incremented, then simply cast to `int` and increment that.

Comment: @Igor: Now replace your example with this: `enum month ...`. Months are contiguous and naturally increment. What then?

Comment: @sbi: Oh months, that changes everything because months are simple . . . hold on, what happens when you increment December? Should it throw an overflow exception, or should it wrap around? It may be obvious to you what happens, but I may require different functionality. There are too many questions around how this *should* work, the language designers were correct to dis-allow this, and let each case be handled individually.

Comment: @Igor: Thank you! I think your answer is extremely useful, however I have accepted sbi's. I think I've kind of cheated a little here as I have basically asked 2 questions in my post. One being in the title, and I think you nailed that in your answer and the other being the last line of my post, for which I think the points go to sbi.

Comment: @BeeBand Hehe, that's OK. I am glad I provided answers to some of your questions.

Comment: @Binary: I'm not sure about your calender, but around here, after December comes January. That's pretty much the same as when you increment `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Anyway, __the question was not about why it is that way__ ("Which sort of makes sense to me..."), __but what to do instead__ ("what's a good substitute?").

Comment: @Sbi: To be honest, I took the question from the title, and didn't read much further. And yes Janurary comes after December, but it's Janurary of *next year*, which may be an imprtant distinction. I'm still glad the language doesn't directly support this, for a variety of reasons :)

Comment: @Binary: Ouch. Obviously, _I_ failed to read the question's title before I wrote this. Sorry for saying this so self-opinionated. I feel bad about that now. `:(`

Comment: @sbi: nay worries pal. If we weren't opinionated we wouldn't contribute so much on SO :) Enjoy the vacation dude ... that said SWITCH OFF YOUR COMPUTER AND GO ENJOY YOURSELF!

Comment: @Binary: @Johannes has a point there, although I'm pretty convinced he's so sure about this because he knows the feeling very well. `:)` Anyway, I had fun, went hiking a lot, but in the morning and evening I tormented my UMTS connection a bit with SO and a few other things. I did not check work stuff, though.

Comment: @sbi: Hiking! Ah man I haven't done any real hiking since I visited Alaska with my brothers and that was 4 1/2 years ago. I'd love to hit the trails again, maybe next summer! Again, enjoy :)

Comment: There is a reason C++ has the concept of UB. The answer to your question is simple: If there is no enum with a value 1 higher than the current one, an increment causes UB.

Comment: @sbi If I'm not mistaken, overflowing a signed integer in an expression is still UB, so "increment std::numeric_limits<int>::max()" is a bad idea (and even if it produced INT_MIN as it would on the most common platforms, that wouldn't be December!). Incrementing std::numeric_limits< **unsigned** int>::max() would create the wraparound you'd like to see though.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Unless you use c++11 and specify the underlying type.

Answer (score 17):

Casting back and forth to/from `int` is of course the obvious solution. Then you make clear that you understand that the addition is happening "outside" the `enum`:

```
nextAvail = static_cast<StackID>(static_cast<int>(nextAvail) + 1);
```

Comment: Hmm. Yes, that was my other option, I just think all those cast's make the code look kind of messy.

Comment: I find myself using C style casts for simple conversions like this one, including all numerical conversions. Your line would simplify to `nextAvail = (StackID)( (int)nextAvail + 1 );` which I find much more readable. There is no possibility that the cast does something else than a static_cast, so there is no need to specify it.

Answer (score 3):

Store `nextAvail` as an `int` instead if you're going to do arithmetic operations on it.

Another option would be to wrap the enum in your own type and overload `operator ++` for it (which also could wrap around or something for instance).

Comment: I think that's what I'm after - wrapping the enum in my own type and then I can do what I like to it. Can you point me in the direction of an example?

Answer (score 2):

An enumeration is semantically supposed to represent a set of distinct related, values.

So you could have

```
enum Colour {RED, GREEN, BLUE};
```

But that should be equivalent to:

```
enum Colour {GREEN, BLUE, RED};
```

The problem is that if you increment an enum then those representations are not the same. `GREEN++` in the first case is not the same as `GREEN++` in the second.

Making your program dependent on the declaration of the enum is a recipe for disaster—maintainers may assume that the order of the enum doesn’t matter, introducing many silent bugs.

Comment: but it is possible to explictly assign the values to enums for example `enum Colour {RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2}`. In that case order doesn't matter.

Comment: True, but then you're going beyond what an enum should be, and crossing into it being a set of key/value pairs.

Comment: it's not clear what you're suggesting when you say "that should be equivalent", can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @BeeBand: Changing the ordering within an enum should not change the behavior of code; but in your case, it will.

Comment: Sure. The first declaration expresses the fact that there are three colours, red, green and blue. Thats all it says. But the second one says the same. A maintainer of the code may, perfectly reasonably, add a colour, YELLOW, between GREEN and BLUE. But any code that assumed (implicitly or explicitly) that GREEN + 1 = BLUE would then break, silently. In short, enums are for expressing sets of values that have a common attribute (in this case that they're colours), rather than a relationship between them (that green comes before blue, or after red etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
nextAvail = (StackID)(nextAvail + 1);
```

Comment: Hello! Please consider providing an explanation to your solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for further help on answering questions.

Comment: OK, using `nextAvail + 1` instead of `nextAvail++` ***is*** actually *a* solution. But can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68033506/edit) an explanation, please? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68033506/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Enums are going to be type `int`, so you can cast them. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
int ndx = (int) StackID.SomeValue;
...
++ndx;
```

This is going to make someone very confused down the line, of course.

It occurs to me that you're using an `enum` where you should be using `const`, or even `#define`. `enum` is most appropriate when you have *arbitrary* values (where the exact value is not meaningful).

Comment: I think you might be right re. const. My code assums that the exact value is meaningful, and as you ( and other posters ) have suggested, breaks the intended meaning of an enum.

Comment: enums are not always of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I've overloaded the `++/--` operator in this way:

```
enum STATE {STATE_1, STATE_2, STATE_3, STATE_4, STATE_5, STATE_6};
```

// Overload the STATE++ operator

```
inline STATE& operator++(STATE& state, int) {
    const int i = static_cast<int>(state)+1;
    state = static_cast<STATE>((i) % 6);
    return state;
}
```

// Overload the STATE-- operator

```
inline STATE& operator--(STATE& type, int) {
    const int i = static_cast<int>(type)-1;

    if (i < 0) {
        type = static_cast<STATE>(6);
    } else {
        type = static_cast<STATE>((i) % 6);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite happy with this C plus C++ solution for a `for` loop incrementing an enum.

```
for (Dwg_Version_Type v = R_INVALID; v <= R_AFTER; v++)
```

=>

```
int vi;
for (Dwg_Version_Type v = R_INVALID; 
     v <= R_AFTER; 
     vi = (int)v, vi++, v = (Dwg_Version_Type)vi)
```

The other solutions here are not C backwards compatible and are quite large.

Comment: What is "Dwg_Version_Type"? It isn't anywhere else on this page.

Comment: Won't the compiler complain? E.g., with [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall)? What was this tested on? Using what compiler (incl. version) and what compiler options? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62415153/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to oprator++, $5.2.6/1 states- "The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object type."

StackID does not fit the bill here. It is of enumeration type.

One option is like this

$5.7/1 - "For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely defined object type and the other shall have integral or enumeration type."

```
enum Possibility {Yes, No, Maybe};

Possibility operator++(Possibility const& r){
   return Possibility(r + 1);   // convert r to integer, add 1, convert back to Enum
}

int main(){
   Possibility p = Yes;
   Possibility p1 = ++p;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious (to the poster as well) that this is illegal, the question was what a good substitute was

Comment: If you overload __prefix__ increment, you should also always overload __postfix__ increment.