# Is it to possible to extend std::tie in c++11 to accept place holders?

Tags: c++, c++11, tie

I was wondering if it is possible to write a `std::tie()`-like function (using template programming) that can bind select components of a tuple only, and bind others to some placeholders like those in `std::bind()`. If so, one needs only declare variables for the parts he/she is interested in.

For example,

```
std::tie(x,_1,y,_2) = (2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: It's not allowed to add anything to the std namespace or change anything within.

Comment: @JohnDibling `std::hash<my_class>` would like a word with you.

Comment: @Yakk:  I take it back.  You can add template specializations.

Comment: @JohnDibling for types dependent on user-defined types only, I believe.  (No `int` or `std::pair<int,int>` specializations)

Comment: @Yakk [litb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390703/enumerate-over-an-enum-in-c) specializes `std::iterator_traits` for `color` in namespace std, so this should be ok right? I mean is this the natural way of doing these things? or are there any caveats?

Comment: @Koushik I believe (I do not have chapter and verse from the standard) if you own a type T, then you can specialize stuff in `std` for the type `T`, or even (if I am right) `std::vector<T>` is fair game.  You do not own any types in `std` nor any built-in types, nor pointers or references to or cv qualifications of things you do not own.  I should find that chapter and verse...

Comment: @Yakk ah that seems fair enough. other than these specializations, std namespace should not be opened for anything else right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for [`std::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore)?

i.e.:

```
std::tie(x,std::ignore,y,std::ignore) = std::make_tuple(2,3,4,5);
```