# Selecting a valid random enum value in a general way

Tags: c++, c++11, random, enums

Let's say we have an enumerated type `E`.

```
enum class E : underlying_type_of_E {
 v1 = uE1,
 v2 = uE2,
   //...
 vN = uEN
};

typedef typename std::underlying_type<E>::type uE;
```

In general, not all values of `uE` are valid values of `E`, because we can choose the relationship between them. Is there a general way of creating random, valid (named in definition, not *assignable*), values of E?
This, for example would not work:

```
std::mt19937 m;
std::uniform_int_distribution<uE> randomUE(0, std::numeric_limits<uE>::max());

E e = static_cast<E>( randomUE(m) );
```

because:

1. Value range may not start from 0
2. Value range may not end at std::numeric_limits::max()
3. Value range may not be a range at all - we can select discrete values for E from uE, for example {1, 3, 64, 272}.

Given that all of the enumerated values are known at compile-time, I cannot imagine a reason why would this be in any way dangerous, or error-prone.

As for a context of why I want such a thing - I'm working on a genetic algorithm that uses templated gene storage. For now, I use enums as chromosomes and store them in `std::vector<bool>` which is converted into `std::vector<enumT>` on demand. The problem with this approach is mutation that flips random bits with given probability. That can cause problems, as it can produce invalid chromosomes that are unnamed enum values.

Comment: Could you have a mapping from `0..N` to your enum ?

Comment: Well, for MY enum - yes, but I'm asking for a general solution. Named enum values are known to the compiler so shouldn't C++ provide this information in some way?

Comment: If you're asking if there is a language-supported way to "enumerate" an `enum` the answer is no, that isn't a feature of C++. There are [tricks you can use if the enum is sequential](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390703/enumerate-over-an-enum-in-c), but that isn't an option for you, so I don't see a general solution forthcoming.

Comment: @tsuki It's not clear what you're asking for.  If you consider arbitrary enums, then what does your random distribution mean in cases like `enum { one = 1, un = 1, eins = 1 };`?

Comment: @JamesKanze I didn't know you could do that with enums! Thanks! Your comment could be posted as an answer as it shows that this isn't possible.

Comment: @tsuki re James' comment - whether it's still possible depends on your requirements: given say `enum E { one = 1, un = 1, two };` you could have a 50/50 chance of generating E(1)/E(2), or a 2/3rds / 1/3rd probability split, or as you say it might be that without being able to say exactly which identifier the enumeration represents you just want to trigger an error or find another approach to your problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you're prepared to use a preprocessor macro to create both the `enum` type and some meta-data about it, but it's a minor hassle:

- Invoke a variadic macro:

  ```
  ENUM(E,
       v1 = uE1,
       v2 = uE2,
       // ...
       vN = uEN);
  ```
- Create a templated class `Incrementing` where successive variables are initialised by an incrementing `static` member by default, but can be assigned to from whatever your underlying type is (e.g. `int`).

  ```
  static Incrementing<E, Underlying> __VA_ARGS__; \
  ```
- Use the values above to initialise a array with the `Incrementing` values (which need an `operator Underlying() const` member).

  ```
  static const Underlying values[] = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  ```

The `values[]` array then contains the named enumeration values....

There's a total overkill version of this concept I wrote years ago [here](https://github.com/boost-vault/Miscellaneous/blob/master/benum_v1.zip), but I'd recommend just starting from scratch given your simple requirements.