# Representing a uniform distribution over the range of an arbitrary enum type

Tags: c++, c++11, random, enums, uniform-distribution

I use the C++ random number utility library in quite a few places. It might not be perfectly comfortable (e.g. no base class for an arbitrary distribution), but - I've learned to live with it.

Now I happen to need to uniformly sample values from an enumerated type. I know, there's a question on that on SO already:

[generating random enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999012/1593077)

however, that one:

1. Assumes all enum values are contiguous, i.e. it won't work for

   ```
   enum Color { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 }
   ```

   where we want each of these three values to be sampled with probability 1/3.
2. Does not provide the functionality of `std::uniform_distribution<>`, i.e. it doesn't work with a random engine you pass it and so on.

Obviously I can't use `std::uniform_int_distribution<Color>`, if only for reason 1 above. What should I do instead?

**Notes:**

- The code must be generic, i.e. the enum type would be a template parameter.
- Since it is likely I would need some instrumentation over just the rough enum, you may assume I have it; just state your assumption explicitly.
- Specifically, and if it helps, suppose I use  [Better Enums](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums), making me fully decked out with all the bells and whistles.
- If there's somehow an idiomatic way of doing this not involving any such instrumentation, that would make for a great answer, but I doubt it.
- C++11/14-only solutions are acceptable.
- Multiple enum identifiers with the same value do not get double the frequency, they're just aliases of each other. If you have a simple solution assuming these do not exist, that would also be relevant, though suboptimal.

Comment: "Idiomatic" and using a third party reflective library are mutually exclusive. What about the library is giving you trouble? It even gives you an example of iterating over it with a ranged-based for.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: You're semantically right. The library is not giving me trouble at all.

Comment: You could remove those values, let the compiler put default values (starting from 0), and initialize an auxiliary `map<Color,int>` with those values, which you could then use along with `std::uniform_distribution<>`.

Comment: If two declared enums have the same value, do you want the distribution to weight their distribution accordingly? e.g. `enum Color { White, Black, Gray, Grey = Gray }`?

Comment: So..what is the issue then? You already know that C++ doesn't have reflection, that's why you're using a reflection library. And there's tons of questions on iterating over enums on SO using standard C++. [Selecting a valid random enum value in a general way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357545/selecting-a-valid-random-enum-value-in-a-general-way?rq=1) might help.

Comment: @ecatmur: Valid point, see edit.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: "*"Idiomatic" and using a third party reflective library are mutually exclusive.*" Nonsense. "idiomatic" does not mean "thing that comes from the C++ standard." Boost invented tons of idioms all on its own. And they still do.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't realize reflection was idiomatic in C++. My apologies.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Well, using a third-party not-very-popular enum-reflection library is itself not idiomatic in C++, so nothing based on it can claim to be idiomatic. I could say I'm looking for a "conditional idiomatic solution"...

Comment: @einpoklum: I think there is no "idiomatic" solution, generating a distribution is just a subtle and complex thing and you should do it out explicitly, in exactly the way you want, for maximum clarity. I don't know any programming language that attempts to define an "idiom" for the problem you are raising.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Generating a uniform distribution over a set of integral values is neither subtle nor complex, mathematically; I don't see why it should be easily possible to have programmatically.

Comment: @einpoklum: Maybe what you really want is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution ? Sorry but I think any code that tries to deduce the distribution parameters from the enum is going to be, at best, an application-specific utility, and at worst, shite.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: That's an interesting idea. I had not used `std::discrete_distribution`, need to give it some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's three implementations of a distribution, in order of ascending complexity:

First, if we can rely on values being distinct or are OK with repeat values being overweighted we can just index the `_values()` container:

```
template<class Enum>
struct SimpleEnumDistribution
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<typename Enum::_integral> dist{0, Enum::_size() - 1};
    template<class Generator> Enum operator()(Generator& g) { return Enum::_values()[dist(g)]; }
};
```

Otherwise, we can use rejection sampling, precalculating the min and max of the range of enum values:

```
template<class Enum>
struct UniformEnumDistribution
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<typename Enum::_integral> dist{
        *std::min_element(Enum::_values().begin(), Enum::_values().end()),
        *std::max_element(Enum::_values().begin(), Enum::_values().end())};
    template<class Generator> Enum operator()(Generator& g)
    {
        for (;;)
            if (auto value = Enum::_from_integral_nothrow(dist(g)))
                return *value;
    }
};
```

If this would be inefficient (perhaps the enum values are sparse) we can compute a lookup table on initialization:

```
template<class Enum>
struct FastUniformEnumDistribution
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist;
    std::array<typename Enum::_integral, Enum::_size()> values;
    FastUniformEnumDistribution()
    {
        std::copy(Enum::_values().begin(), Enum::_values().end(), values.data());
        std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
        dist.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>::param_type{0u, static_cast<std::size_t>(
            std::distance(values.begin(), std::unique(values.begin(), values.end())) - 1)});
    }
    template<class Generator> Enum operator()(Generator& g)
    {
        return Enum::_from_integral_unchecked(values[dist(g)]);
    }
};
```

[Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PzaPMcZR4wKdfkuM).

Comment: I guess that's good enough for me. Although this should be beefed up to meet all of the RandomNumberDistribution concept requirements.

Answer (score 4):

With use of [Better Enums](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/tutorial/Iteration.html), this problem may be resolved this way:

```
template<typename T>
typename T get_uniform_value(std::default_random_engine& eng)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, T::_size() - 1);
    return T::_values()[dist(eng)];
}
```

Usage example:

```
BETTER_ENUM(Channel, int, Red, Green = 2, Blue) // Enum to generate random values of
...
std::default_random_engine rng(std::random_device{}());
Channel r = get_uniform_value<Channel>(rng); // Uniformly distributed between 0, 2 and 3
```

Comment: Shouldn't `get_uniform_value` take the PRNG by reference so it is actually modified?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it should. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

I would say the more idiomatic would be to create an array and choosing index from the array:

```
 template <typename Rnd>
 Color RandomColor(Rnd& rnd)
 {
     const std::array<Color, 3u> colors {Color::Red, Color::Green, Color::Blue};

     std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, colors.size() - 1);
     return colors[dist(rnd)];
 }
```

*Better Enums* seems to allow to not create the array manually with `Color::_values`:

```
 template <typename BetterEnum, typename Rnd>
 BetterEnum RandomBetterEnum(Rnd& rnd)
 {
     std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, BetterEnum::_size() - 1);
     return BetterEnum::_values()[dist(rnd)];
 }
```

Comment: If you can't generalize your implementation to take the Enum type as a template parameter, then that's not good enough.

Comment: Without extra library, as we don't have reflection, you have to construct the array. It seems that the library you use provide this functionality, so it can be generalized for enum managed by BetterEnum.

Comment: @Jarod42, sure you can.  SFINAE on the return type using `typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<BetterEnum>::value, BetterEnum>::type`

To be "more correct", you may want to use `size_t` instead of `int` but that's being very nit-picky.

Answer (score 0):

In [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999012/generating-random-enums), it is assumed that you want the uniform distribution over the *enumerator values*.

However, "uniform distribution over an enum-type" might also mean, uniform distribution over the *range* of the enum, which typically means, all the possible values of the underlying type which was selected by the implementation.

There are other fundamental problems:

In the case that you showed

```
enum Color { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 }
```

Presumably, the uniform distribution that you want is from 0 to 7 (each enumerator possible OR'd together using bitmasks).

Suppose the enum were:

```
enum Color { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 3 }
```

Then presumably you only want 1, 2, 3 in your distribution.

I think you can't expect the compiler or any template code to understand your intent -- any "enum -> uniform distribution" code would require hints so that it knows which enumerators should be |'d with combinations of the others and which ones are simply options.

So in short, I think you should do exactly what the question you linked to does, and generate the appropriate distribution over `int`'s or whatever, and then `static_cast` it to the enum. And don't try to use some template solution that tries to read your mind for every possible enum.

Comment: In the Color example, the unfirom distribution should be 1 w.p. 1/3, 2 w.p. 1/3, 3 w.p. 1/3. I'll make that clearer. And - I can certainly expect this to be understood if I don't just define my enum that way, but use a more complex mechanism - see the notes.